# Input and spacing issue in batch

Tags: input, batch-file, spaces

I am required to input a file path for a batch file I made.

```
C:\PATH\TO\DESKTOP>Batch "File Path With Spaces"
```

The batch file uses %1.
I believe the spaces in the file path is causing problems.
I tried messing with quotation marks, no luck.

Does anyone know?

Comment: That is difficult to answer without seeing the batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where your batch file has `%1` or `"%1"` replace them with `"%~1"`

`%~1` removes any quotes that may be around the string, and `"%~1"` replaces all strings with the quotes so that spaces and poison characters are protected.

Answer (score 0):

**If you do not require any other arguments its very simple:**

In your batch file say you wanted to echo "text" into a file. Instead of referring to the argument as `%1` refer to it as `%*` (which includes `%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 ...`).

```
C:\PATH\TO\DESKTOP>Batch C:\users\%username%\file name with spaces\File Name.txt
```

and in Batch.bat:

```
Echo "text" >> "%*"
```

And your done. Just remember to surround the `%*` with double quotes and you should be fine!

Mona